# A propriedade ConnectionString não foi inicializada

Tags: c#

Estou tentando criar um cadastro de categorias, no cadastro deu tudo certo, mas quando vou fazer a localização dos registros adicionados ao cadastro retorna sempre o mesmo erro:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> "A propriedade ConnectionString não foi inicializada."

como mostra a imagem abaixo:

[image: Erro]

Aguardo respostas

Comment: A primeira vista, o objeto conexao que é recebido no construtor não está com a connectionString preenchida. Você deve olhar no trecho de código que define qual connectionstring usar do seu app.config/web.config e verificar se o nome ela no arquivo de configuração bate com que está sendo usado no código.

Comment: Mostra o construtor dessa class e a class DALConexao também.

Comment: Poste o código do método `Incluir`, por favor. Provavelmente nesse método você deve fazer uma atribuição á propriedade `conexao.StringConxao` e esqueceu de fazer isso no método `Localizar`

Comment: Coloque o código completo da sua classe, e não o print

Answer (score 1):

O objeto conexao que você esta passando no parâmetro do SqlDataAdapter não foi instanciado.

Tente o seguinte:

```
public DataTable Localizar(String Valor)
{
    DataTable tabela = new DataTable();
    conexao = new DALConexao();
    ....
}
```

ou verifique o método de cadastro como você instanciou o objeto conexão.

Comment: @Luiz Paulo Alvim Soares Se a resposta lhe foi útil, se puder marque-a como aceita `√`, assim quando outros usuários visualizarem sua questão verão que já tem uma resposta correta e aceita por você.